# How to detect that keyboard combination pressed in app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example, I when press `ctrl+s` it will call an action to save something; or when I press combination `ctrl + z` it will undo an action.

I tried to handle onKeyPress event on div but it doesn't work

```
    <div
      onKeyDown={() => {
        console.log("key press");
      }}
    > 
     ...
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript to create a function where you record what you have pressed in an array (on ***keydown***) and then on ***keyup*** check that array to see if it includes certain key combinations and then return the desired function if the condition is met. Then clear the array after. Like so:

```
let pressed = [];
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    pressed.push(event.which);
    return (function() {
        function checkKeys(key1, key2) {
            return pressed.includes(key1) && pressed.includes(key2)
        }
        document.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
            if (checkKeys(17, 90)) { //ctrl + z - insert the keycodes here
                // call the UNDO function
            } else if (checkKeys(17, 83)) { //ctrl + s - insert the keycodes here
                // call the SAVE function
            }
            pressed = [];
        });
    })();
});
```

You can use [this website](https://keycode.info/) to check what the keycodes are for all the different keys.

Check out a JSFiddle example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Ludolfyn/czygs04t/). Just make sure you focus on the display window when you press the keys.

Answer (score 0):

you can go with below code:

```js
<div
      onKeyDown={(event) => {
        if(event.ctrlKey && event.key === "Z") {
          console.log("Ctrl+z captured")
        }
      }}
    > 
     ...
    </div>
```